# Why does Hibernate/Spring generate foreign key on ID field. Causes foreign key volation

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

I am new to Hibernate/Spring and am having an issue with autogenerated foreign keys and constrain violation.  I have the following class properties:

```
@Id
@Column(name="MEDICATION_ID", nullable = false)
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private long medicationId;

@Column(name="PATIENT_ID")
private long patientId;

private long dosageMg;           // dose for patient in mgs
private long active;             // active = 1, inactive = 0
private String medicationName;  // name, oxy, etc.
private String  medicationCode;  // global identifier for this medications
private long activeDate;
private long inactiveDate;
```

When I start my server I notice that it generates the following code foreign key on the medicationID

```
Hibernate: alter table medication add constraint FK_dbfuno3knrhmabosmfty7l3ta foreign key (all_medications_MEDICATION_ID) references medication
```

Then when it tries to execute this insert statement from my import.sql it throws a constraint violation error.

```
delete from medication;
insert into medication (medication_id, patient_id, dosage_mg, active, medication_name, medication_code, active_date,inactive_date  ) values (1000, 101, 10, 1, 'Oxy', 'oxy_10', 10000, 50000);
```

The error reads:

```
Caused by: org.hsqldb.HsqlException: integrity constraint violation: NOT NULL check constraint; SYS_CT_10127 table: MEDICATION column: ALL_MEDICATIONS_MEDICATION_ID
```

Any ideas on why this foreign key was generated and how I can get around this constraint violation.

Thanks!

Comment: The code you have posted is `Medication.java` entity? and is that complete code?

Comment: Could you show us the entire Entity? .. I suspect something missing, like @Chaitanya

Comment: Not it is not the entire class definition, but it is all of the properties in the class.  The only code left out is the getters/setters for the properties.

Comment: The problem is a join against the table.